# Combine two vectors of different length based on common values and expand the shorter

Tags: r

I have two vectors with some values in common, but of different length:

```
x <- 1:10
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

y <- c(3, 5, 8)
# [1]  3  5 8
```

I'd like to combine these two vectors into a dataframe and produce the following result:

```
data.frame(big = x,
           small = c(NA, NA,  3, NA,  5, NA, NA,  8, NA, NA))
#    big small
# 1    1    NA
# 2    2    NA
# 3    3     3
# 4    4    NA
# 5    5     5
# 6    6    NA
# 7    7    NA
# 8    8     8
# 9    9    NA
# 10  10    NA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767244/matching-values-from-two-vectors-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to index the short vector using the `match` between the long and short, with the `nomatch` argument set to `NA` ("*the value to be returned in the case when no match is found*").

```
data.frame(big = x,
           small = y[match(x, y, nomatch = NA)])
```